# Hay alguna manera de hacer los diccionarios de python en js?

Tags: javascript, python, web

pues eso, hay algúna manera o algo parecido que pueda hacer esto pero en js:

```
diccionario = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}
```

esto es de python y estoy buscando alguna manera de hacerlo en js ya que no estoy acostumbrado a este lenguaje, por lo que tengo entendido se puede hacer con un map, pero lo veo algo incomodo, hay alguna otra manera?, o se puede usar python en el frontend?

Comment: En js sería así `let diccionario = {'a': 'b', 'c': 'd'}; dic['a']`

Comment: Ese código es javascript válido, crea un objeto con dos claves (a y c) con los valores 'b' y 'd'

Comment: a... jajjaja Creo que me falta leer la documentacion jajaja, muchas gracias amigos

Comment: Realmente faltó fue probar! No veo por qué el miedo a ver qué hace ese código en JS y ver si estalla en llamas xD

Comment: Se llama Objeto en JS, nada mas. podes declararlo como const, let o var, cada uno va a tener propiedades distintas, pero al fin de cuentas es una varible del tipo objeto, luego puedes acceder a sus propiedades como objeto.propiedad o como objeto["propiedad"]